# Supported Azure DevOps Server versions for DevOps Service import

Tags: azure-devops

Since last week I am getting the following error running the DevOps Service migration tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274&culture=de-de&country=de):

[Error] VS403265: The collection's Azure DevOps Server milestone is not supported by the data migration tool: Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1. Please upgrade your Azure DevOps Server to one of the supported versions. The data migration guide has the latest supported versions: https://aka.ms/AzureDevOpsImport

However the documentation ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops#supported-tfs-versions-for-import checked on 23/01/2023) names the following versions as supported:

- Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.2
- Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.1

Can somebody tell which versions are supported in the future? Is it enough to upgrade to 2020.1.2?

Checked the documentation, seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, only the latest 2 versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import. There has been a banner in the migration tool for over a month warning that 2020.1.1 support will be dropped a few weeks following the 2022 release.

The documentation looks to have been updated now as well:
[Supported Versions for import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops#supported-azure-devops-server-versions-for-import)
[image]

The Oldest of the 3 versions, 2020.1.1 is no longer supported and the executable will be removed in the very near future.  the best path forward is to upgrade to 2020.1.2 or 2022RTM, download the appropriate Migrator tool and redo the steps starting at prepare.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the version that you`ve downloaded?

[image]

I think, you may install the last patch to be sure of the version compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-202011-patch-4-release-date-january-26-2022